# How to force chromium's garbage collector to run in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, chromium, yocto

I'm building a small HTML based software for an embedded system that has a client and server.
The software works on a single tab that is active all the time.
The client and the server exchange messages all the time.
After ~50 hours, the client is crushing.
After a brief investigation, It seems that the client keeps consuming memory until there is none left and a call to allocate new memory fails.
Then i get "Aw, snap" on the web page.

I tried debugging using chromium's "developer tools".
It seems that when i press the "Collect garbage" button, most of the memory clears up.

[image]

Here's the code for the client after reducing it as much as i can:

```js
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8070');
socket.binaryType = "blob";
socket.onopen = handleOpen;
socket.onmessage = handleSocketMessage;

function handleOpen() {
  console.log('socket is ready');
}

function handleSocketMessage(message) {
  // console.log(message);
}
```

The code runs on Variscite's imx6 SOM.
The OS is made with the Yocto project version Sumo.
Chromium version is 67.0.3396.99

Browsing online, chromium/chrome doesn't seem to allow manually calling the garbage collector.
Is there a way to go around this?
Can you think of a different possible solution?
What else could cause the client to consume all the OS's memory and then crush?

Comment: Maybe you keep opening new websockets without closing them?

Comment: The code for the client is mentioned above. As you can see, there is only a single call that creates a new web socket in the first line.